# Trying to use command npm-start, it's failing to compile for a unknown reason. Any suggestions?

Tags: reactjs, npm

The error message below is what happens when I run `npm-start` to begin my development server. Any suggestions or help on why this is occurring?

```
./node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/integrations/console.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'console' in 
'C:\Users\ssand\wave-portal-2.0\wave_portal_2.0\node_modules\@sentry\node\esm\integrations'
```

Comment: Try to delete `node-modules`, run `npm cache clean -f` and then `npm i`